# Is it possible to configure the similarity threshold used by Azure Repos?

Tags: git, azure-devops, azure-repos

My command line git shows the files are renamed. It appears the default similarity threshold is 50%.

However, both Azure Repos and Visual Studio show the files as being deleted and added. From which I conclude both of them use a higher similarity threshold.

Is it possible to change it for Azure Repos?

Comment: Note it may change depending on your view. I think in both VS and AzDev (not sure if Repos is different), I've seen both adds/deletes and moves depending on the view. For example, in VS, I think comparing commits shows add/deletes, but viewing the specific commits shows moves. Maybe this is also true in AzDev at the commit view, versus, say, a PR view.

Comment: In this case Azure DevOps shows the same both in PR and commit view.

Comment: I can't find anything documented either way. I'm guessing the answer is no...

Comment: Side note, I usually create an extra commit just for renames without any edits, just to avoid this issue. (I'm guessing you already know this and didn't have a choice here...)

Comment: Actually, I am doing it right now. But I just did not expect it to happen here. This is the first time I notice this much difference in the history reporting by Azure DevOps/VS and git command line. I thought both have the same default.